# Laravel saveMany() saving blank database rows

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using saveMany to save a user id and a checked checkbox values in a table.

```
    $userAccounts = array();
    $checkboxes = Input::get('accounts');
    foreach ($checkboxes as $accountId) {
        $userAccounts[] = new \UserExternalAccount([
            'external_account_id' => $accountId,
            'user_id' => $user->id
        ]);
    }
    $user->external_user_accounts()->saveMany($userAccounts);
```

This works, but in my table I am getting extra rows added which are mainly blank.

If I tick 1 checkbox then 2 are added to my table:

```
id  user_id  account_id  created_at           updated_at
54  114      4           2015-05-05 15:17:16  2015-05-05 15:17:16
55  114      54          NULL                 NULL
```

The top row is correct, but the second row has an account id of the previous row and no updated / created values.

If I dd() the userAccounts array it only shows 1, also if I dd() the saveMany() it also only shows 1 item in the array.

Im out of ideas where the extra rows are coming from, any ideas?

Comment: have the same problem. Moreover in one piece code this problem does not happen, in another always does :/
did you solve this problem?

Comment: Any progress on this issue?